# Can we solve for $\delta$ in $\frac{π}{2} - \frac{R}{r}β = \arcsin\biggl(\frac{(R+r)\sin(δ)}{r}\biggr)+\frac{R}{r}δ$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Solve for $\delta$:
>
> $$\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{R}{r}β = \arcsin\left(\frac{(R+r)\sin \delta}{r}\right)+\frac{R}{r}δ$$

My problem is that I can't comprehend how to get both $\delta$s out of a trig operation at the same time. If I apply 'sine' to both sides, I understand the 'arcsine' will be canceled, but does this operation apply 'sine' to $\frac{R}{r}\delta$ on the right, making it $\sin\left(\frac{R}{r}\delta\right)$ ???

Is this problem a question of a trigonometric derivative?

---

My second question is perhaps a more important one. I do not have a textbook pertaining to trigonometry, much less trigonometric derivatives. The math book I currently own is about matrices and calculus, but only having to do with 'regular' derivatives; no trigonometry derivatives, obviously.

What is a good textbook for trigonometry (regular trig-algebra)?
What is a good textbook for trigonometry derivatives? Is there a textbook that contains both of these subjects?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: You need a numerical method. Remember that $x=\cos(x)$ does not show analytical solutions. If you give test values for $r,R,\beta$, I could shos you.

Comment: You should ask for textbook recommendations in a separate question. That said, do a search first. I'm pretty sure that people have asked for such recommendations a few times.

Comment: I have rolled-back the question, since your last edit changed the nature of the problem in a way that invalidated the efforts of an answerer. If you want to ask the question in your edit, post it separately.

Answer (score 2):

Letting $Q = R/r$ and rearranging a bit gives

$$
\frac{\pi}{2} - Q\beta - Q\delta = \arcsin \bigl( (Q + 1) \sin \delta \bigr)
$$

then taking $\sin(\cdot)$ of both sides and using $\sin (\pi/2 - x) = \cos x$ results in

$$
\cos \bigl( Q(\beta + \delta) \bigr) = (Q + 1) \sin \delta.
$$

If $Q = 1$ then the equation can be solved exactly. Otherwise, you can rewrite the equation as

$$
\delta = f(\delta) = \arcsin \left( \frac{\cos \bigl( Q(\beta + \delta) \bigr)}{Q + 1} \right)
$$

and repeatedly apply $f$ to some initial guess for a solution $\delta$. It turns out that this [fixed-point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) converges in this particular case.