# Find θ: $β=\arctan\frac{(R+r)·\sin(θ)-r·\sin(θ(1+\frac{R}{r}))}{(R+r)·\cos(θ)-r·\cos(θ(1+\frac{R}{r}))}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The parametric formula for an epicycloid is:
$$x=(R+r)·\cos(θ)-r·\cos\Biggl(θ\biggl(1+\frac{R}{r}\biggr)\Biggr)\\
y=(R+r)·\sin(θ)-r·\sin\Biggl(θ\biggl(1+\frac{R}{r}\biggr)\Biggr)$$

The angle θ is the angle between the positive x-axis and a line running from the origin through the center of the generating circle (with radius r).

If instead of the angle $\theta$, you are given the angle between the positive x-axis and the end of the curve (we will call this angle $\beta$), how do I find $\theta$?

$$β = \arctan\frac{(R+r)·\sin(θ)-r·\sin\Biggl(θ\biggl(1+\frac{R}{r}\biggr)\Biggr)}{(R+r)·\cos(θ)-r·\cos\Biggl(θ\biggl(1+\frac{R}{r}\biggr)\Biggr)}$$

Comment: Without specific $R$ and $r$ I don't think anyone can simplify it!

Comment: I shall not comment after looking at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872704/can-we-solve-for-delta-in-frac%cf%802-fracrr%ce%b2-arcsin-biggl-frac

Comment: Don't worry ! I shall for ever remember the word you used in a comment which, being very brave, you deleted.

Comment: I have rolled-back the question to a version that made some sense. Please don't vandalize questions (even your own) that invalidates the answers you have received.

Comment: FYI: I managed to flag your most-recent insult to Claude, but only after taking a screenshot. Please respect the users here that are trying to help you.

Comment: @Blue. Thanks for your care. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Define $t=1+\frac R r$ to make the equation
$$\beta=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t \sin (\theta )-\sin (t\,\theta  )}{t \cos (\theta )-\cos (t\,\theta)}\right)$$

If $\beta$ is small, composing Taylor series, you would have
$$\beta=\frac{ t (t+1)}{6} \theta ^3+O\left(\theta ^5\right)$$ and then an estimate of $\theta$.

Otherwise, I suppose that a numerical method (such as Newton) would be required.

Let us try with $R=2r$, that is to say $t=3$ and suppose $\beta=1$; this would give $\theta_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}$ and the iterates would be

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \theta_n \\
 0 & 0.793700526 \\
 1 & 1.229465478 \\
 2 & 1.185508561 \\
 3 & 1.185309641 \\
 4 & 1.185309636
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We could have a better approximation using the simplest Padé approximant; this would give
$$\beta=\frac{10t (t+1)\, \theta ^3 }{60+3(t^2+10t+1)\, \theta ^2 }$$ and then a cubic equation. For the worked example, this would give $\theta_0 \approx  1.29716$.

Comment: @user101434. Solving which equation ? $\beta$ is given, no ?

Comment: Oh! My mistake, I meant to say "theta".
Would this be a derivative? I know nothing of derivatives, and perhaps that is why I am having so much trouble.

Comment: @user101434. OK ! Sincerely, I think that only numerical methods could work. No hope to get an explicit equation such as $\theta=f(t,\beta)$. Newton method would work perfect; you could make it using Excel.

Comment: @user101434. For sure, I may be wrong ! Very seriously speaking, I would enjoy to see a solution. If you have any, could you tell more ? Thanks.

Comment: @user101434. I upvoted your question. Now, post, please.

Comment: @user101434. Was it a trick to get points ? In any manner, if you have a solution, I do not understand the reason of your post. I am still waiting for what you spoke about in comments. It would be very unfair not to do it.

Comment: Perhaps my only question is:

What is:
arcsin(sin(x)·y+sin(z)) = ?